# DllImport fails on windows XP SP3 but works on windows 7

Tags: c#, c, windows, winapi, dll

I created a sample application from this site
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9826/How-to-create-a-DLL-library-in-C-and-then-use-it-w
It creates a C code and consumes in C# application.

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 extern "C"
 {
  __declspec(dllexport) void DisplayHelloFromDLL()
   {
   printf("Hello from DLL !\n");
   }
 }
```

The C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;     // DLL support

class HelloWorld
{
  [DllImport("TestLib.dll")]
  public static extern void DisplayHelloFromDLL ();

  static void Main ()
  {
    Console.WriteLine ("This is C# program");
    DisplayHelloFromDLL ();
  }
}
```

This works well on Windows 7. I have built the code on Visual studio 2010 on windows 7 machine. When i try to run the exe on windows XP it fails with following exception being thrown:Unable to load DLL 'TestLib.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

Comment: Do you have the VS2010 C runtime deployed on the XP machine?

Comment: It's usually a good idea to name the execution environment. In this case, though, this obscured your view: This is not related to "Windows 7 vs. Windows XP" but rather "dev machine vs. regular machine". @Frédéric already hinted towards that.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi No i do not have visual studio 2010 deployed on win xp.

Comment: @IInspectable : Its only this code that does not work with dllImport. But the following dllImport works <http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.charset(v=vs.110).aspx>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely explanation, with probability close to 1 is that the Windows 7 machine has the MSVC runtime installed, but the XP machine does not.

Download the redistributable for the VS2010 MSVC runtime and install it on the XP machine. Your code should then work. The runtime is already on the Windows 7 machine because that is your development machine.

FWIW, your p/invoke is not quite correct. It fails to specify the calling convention. It should be:

```
[DllImport("TestLib.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void DisplayHelloFromDLL();
```

Comment: Hi. i added calling convention. Still no luck. Gives the same error

Comment: Of course not. That's not your main problem. You should install the runtime as I said.

Comment: I installed the runtime too now. Yet it fails to load the dll. Same error.

Comment: What exactly did you install? Have you tried running through Dependency Walker in Profile mode to see where the failure occurs. What SP is installed on the XP machine?

Comment: Hey It worked. Thank you for the suggestion on dependency walker. I figured out that it still complained msvcr100.dll was missing. re-installed the redistributable. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Compile a simple hello world executable console application on Windows 7, and try to run that alone on Windows XP. It should be more verbose than a DLL. It will either complain that it's lacking some DLL's or there's a 32/64 bit mismatch.

Comment: Hi. I tried a simple hello world exe like you said. It works fine in both without any change.